# Gradientfill for custom shape control c++

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I want to draw gradient fill for one edge for a rounded corner rectangle.I tried to use

```
GradientFill
```

API in combination of

```
BeginPath()
EndPath()
SelectClipPath()
```

API's but it did not work.

Since RoundRect is windows API, do we have some windows API to perform gradient fill on Rounded corner rectangle.

More specific can we limit gradient fill to any of the edges?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, this kind of thing screams out for a .Net/GDI+ solution.  If that's at all possible...

Comment: any pointers for good resource for gdi+ using with C++

Comment: can we use gdi and gdi+ in same application?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using GDI.  The sequence of functions is:

```
BeginPath
RoundRect
EndPath
WidenPath
SelectClipPath
GradientFill
```

This will draw the entire border of the rounded rectangle using a gradient.  The key is `WidenPath`.  This creates a new path in the device context equivalent to the area that would be filled if the old path was stroked with the current pen.

If you just want a gradient on a single edge, do the GradientFill over a single edge.  You can easily calculate where the edges are.

**Update**

If you also want to fill the interior with a gradient fill, first use the same sequence of functions without the `WidenPath`, then draw the outline.  Combine the two with something like `BeginPath, RoundRect, EndPath, SaveDC, SelectClipPath, GradientFill, RestoreDC, WidenPath, SelectClipPath, GradientFill`.